# Need convert varchar to numeric and get datagridview current cell value

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I have table 'USER' in my DB with(ID[varchar] and PK NOT AI, name[varchar], surname[varchar])
In my c# code I have a datagridview. I display all data from my table 'USER'.

For example:

```
1234 - John - Smith
1347 - Jack - Russel
```

After I need click on grid cell, and selected data must be displayed in textboxes. For example I click on 1234 cell and in textBox1 I'll display 'name', in textBox2 - 'lastname'. It makes by ID.

My code is:

```
connecClass connStr = new connectClass();
DataGridViewRow currentrow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
string currStr = currentrow .Cells[0].Value.ToString();
DataTable tableData = connStr.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID=" +
                                    currentrow);
```

And I get an error: Error converting type data varchar to numeric
After I tried another way, replace .Cells[0] to .Cells["ID"], but get an error: cannot find column ID.

May be you can help me or some other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You say that the column ID is of type `varchar`. Maybe try the following:

```
DataTable tableData = connStr.query("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE ID='" +
                                    currStr + "'");
```

In other words, put the argument `currStr` between single quotes (').

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try. Is it reason for my error? I mean single quotes

Comment: @JohnSmith, I'm not sure. You got a type mismatch problem somewhere where you supply a varchar value while a numeric value was expected. You say your ID column is of type varchar... hence my suggestion to put single quotes around the parameter value.